# Using NLog with NServiceBus 3

Tags: c#, nservicebus, nlog

Is it possible to get NServiceBus3 log to NLog? and if so does anyone have any examples of how to do this?

### EDIT: Solution

If anyone is interested here's my implementation of the appender, some of the log4net levels are probably not mapped to sensible NLog areas but it should give other people at least a start point

```
// Setup a custom formatter like the one below to get nice exception logging
    //<target name="YourLogFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/../logs/YourLogFile.log" archiveFileName="${basedir}/../logs/archives/YourLogFile.{#####}.log" 
    //layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}${onexception:|EXCEPTION OCCURRED\:${exception:format=type,message,method:maxInnerExceptionLevel=5:innerFormat=shortType,message,method}}" 
    //archiveEvery="Day" archiveNumbering="Sequence" maxArchiveFiles="14" />
    public class NlogAppenderForLog4Net : AppenderSkeleton
    {
        protected override void Append(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            var Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(loggingEvent.LoggerName);


            if (loggingEvent.Level == Level.Fatal)
            {
                if (loggingEvent.ExceptionObject != null)
                {
                    Logger.FatalException(loggingEvent.RenderedMessage, loggingEvent.ExceptionObject);
                }
                else
                {
                    Logger.Fatal(loggingEvent.RenderedMessage);
                }
            }
            //if its an error
            else if(loggingEvent.Level == Level.Error ||
                    loggingEvent.Level == Level.Critical ||
                    loggingEvent.Level == Level.Emergency)
            {
                if(loggingEvent.ExceptionObject != null)
                {
                    Logger.ErrorException(loggingEvent.RenderedMessage, loggingEvent.ExceptionObject);
                }
                else{
                    Logger.Error(loggingEvent.RenderedMessage);
                }
            }
            //if its a warning
            else if (loggingEvent.Level == Level.Warn)
            {
                if (loggingEvent.ExceptionObject != null)
                {
                    Logger.WarnException(loggingEvent.RenderedMessage, loggingEvent.ExceptionObject);
                }
                else
                {
                    Logger.Warn(loggingEvent.RenderedMessage);
                }
            }
            //if its info
            else if (loggingEvent.Level == Level.Info || loggingEvent.Level == Level.Notice)
            {
                Logger.Info(loggingEvent.RenderedMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.Trace(loggingEvent.RenderedMessage);
            }
        }
    }
```

and heres how i wire it up in NServiceBus

```
.Log4Net<NlogAppenderForLog4Net>(a => { })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without forking you could create your own appender for Log4Net to redirect to NLog.  [Here](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/logging/) are some more details on logging in NSB.

Answer (score 2):

There are existing implementations of NLogAppender, that you can use...  For example there  is log4net.NLogAppender which can be found both at [GitHub](https://github.com/lanwin/log4net.NLogAppender): and installed from NuGet.

Comment: Cheers ill look into it at some stage, this is working for me at the moment though

Comment: Just a heads up that as of 10/22/2012 the log4net.NLogAppender NuGet package fails to install alongside NServiceBus.  They require different versions of log4net and NuGet can't resolve the dependency.